# Postgres: How to search for a value on _all_ fields in an object in a json-type column without knowing the keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In a Postgres database I have a column of type jsonb which contains a generic object whose keys I cannot predict:

```
{"some_key":"value", "another_unpredictable_key":"another value}
```

Is it possible to search for a particular value in all of the fields without knowing the keys? Sth. like

```sql
select * from ... where column_whatever->>'*' = '...'
```

Comment: When you have to perform some SQL searches on a JSON field, this means that storing those datas as JSON was not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for you effort, but you do not know the context. It makes sense indeed in our case, I can tell you :-)

Comment: an EAV design could have fit better your need

Comment: No, it does not. It is a one dimensional object with values of type string. EAV has so many downsides that it is not worth it.

On the other hand it is not enought to use a nosql databases instead of postgres. The json type of Postgres fits best for it. And just because there is a small struggle on one single use case you would not change the data structure when it fits perfect for the rest.

Comment: I don't like EAV structure, but I prefer it over searching in a serialized field. EAV can be indexed.

Comment: I don't search over a serialized field indeed but over a structured field which is of type json. Postgres also can index json fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn the json value into multiple rows (of key/value pairs) and search in the result of that:

```
select * 
from some_table t 
where exists (select * 
              from jsonb_each_text(t.jsonb_column) as x(ky,val)
              where x.val = 'some value');
```

[`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) returns one row for each top-level key/value pair. This does not handle nested keys.

Comment: Thanks alot - That was exactly what I was looking for.